# How to pass extended parameter to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a function so that I can call my array object elements multiple times (since I have them quite a lot, returned from the sql query).

```
removeDuplicates(arr, x){
    var tmp = [];
    var tmp2=[];
    for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        if(tmp.indexOf(arr[i].id) == -1){
        tmp.push(arr[i].id); //always id
        tmp2.push(arr[i].x);  //for example arr[i].name
        }
    }
    return tmp2;
}
```

If I do it like that and call the method like this:

```
 removeDuplicates(arraytag2, arraytag2.name);
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: you mean `tmp2.push(arr[i][x]);` ?

Comment: If arraytag2 is array how can you write arraytag2.name ?

Comment: I know that I can't it should be arraytag2[counter].name, just trying to find a shortcut here..

Comment: @JAG, no I'm not looking for that..

Comment: when you say, 'it doesn't work', what do you really mean? It throws an error? or just unexpected results? Anyway If you're passing the full object arr, to the function, there's no need to pass arr.name.

Comment: I know but I don't want to have 10 methods just to retrieve the object param...

Comment: @eugen_sunic If you want to traverse over all the parameters of object there is no need to 2nd params u can direct do a for(var prop in arr[i]) else if you want selected property use 2nd params as array of properties u want

Comment: I guess I'll do it that way, I just wante to find out how to achieve it this way... With a second parameter..

Comment: If I understood you well, you need JAG's solution but invoke this like `removeDuplicates(arraytag2, "name");`

Comment: This doesn't work @barbsan

Comment: it's quite difficult to understand, and therefore help you, without more detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the amazing `filter` function in arrays?

You then can make your own validation inside the function item by item and it's own properties.

```js
function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}

var arr = ["hello", "bye", "hola", "adios", "see you", "hello", "hola"];
var uniqArr = uniq(arr);

console.log(arr);
console.log(uniqArr);
```

Comment: tnx, but I'm not looking for filtering..

Comment: @eugen_sunic, but you need to filter duplicates in order to remove them, isn't this what are you looking for?